# Pyserial not finding ports in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with a device using Python 3.10.6 in Ubuntu 22.04 but can't. I have been using this device for years with previous Ubuntu versions, so I know how to use it.

Test code:

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports

p = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
print(p)
```

prints `[]`. If I run

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

I get `no ports found`.

How can I fix this?